# Ideal object-oriented design

Tags: c#, oop

I realise this has a very broad title.

My knowledge of OO is lacking as I have not done it in a few years although I think my concepts are correct.

I am creating a custom PerformanceMonitor that reads real-time information from your computers hardware. I'm coding this is C#. Example classes:

**Machine**

```
namespace PerformanceMonitor
{
    public static class Machine
    {
        public static CPU cpu { get; set; } = new CPU();
        public static RAM ram { get; set; } = new RAM();
        public static List<GPU> gpus { get; set; } = new List<GPU>();
        public static List<Drive> drives { get; set; } = new List<Drive>();

        static Machine() {}
    }
}
```

**CPU**

```
namespace PerformanceMonitor
{
    public class CPU
    {
        public List<CPUCore> cpuCores { get; set; } = new List<CPUCore>();
        public bool HyperThreaded { get; set; } = false;

        public int ClockBusSpeed_current { get; set; }
        public int ClockBusSpeed_max { get; set; }

        public int TemperaturePackage_current { get; set; }
        public int TemperaturePackage_max { get; set; }

        public int LoadTotal_current { get; set; }
        public int LoadTotal_max { get; set; }

        public int PowerPackage_current { get; set; }
        public int PowerPackage_max { get; set; }

        public int PowerGraphics_current { get; set; }
        public int PowerGraphics_max { get; set; }

        public int PowerDRAM_current { get; set; }
        public int PowerDRAM_max { get; set; }

        public int PowerCores_current { get; set; }
        public int PowerCores_max { get; set; }

        public CPU() {}
    }
}
```

**CPUCore**

```
namespace PerformanceMonitor
{
    public class CPUCore : CPU
    {
        public CPUCore() {}
    }
}
```

**Machine** is a top-level class, if you will. Every time an instance of Machine is created, an instance of all other classes listed are created as well. For example, if you wanted to set that the CPU is hyperthreaded, you would do something to this effect in **Program.cs**:

```
private static Machine machine = new Machine();
...
if (NumberOfCores * 2 == NumberOfLogicalProcessors) {
    machine.cpu.HyperThreaded = true;
}
```

So you will access everything through the Machine class.

Every time the program is run, only 1 instance of each class will be created (except CPUCore, GPU and Drive - this is why I'm attempting to use `static`)

The **Machine** class (and therefore, any class) will only be accessed through the **Program** class. This class will also be the only one interacting with the WMI to get the required information.

My questions are:

- Even though nothing is in the constructor of each class, will the instance see that the class has those specific attributes or do they have to be newly created in the constructor? i.e:

  `public static CPU cpu { get; set; }
  ...
  static Machine() {
      cpu = new Cpu();
  }`
- Am I using the 'static' keyword correctly here?
- Should/can I also implement the list of classes as static even though the class itself is not? I.e:

  `public static List<GPU> gpus`
- Should I also implement the keyword `sealed` in any of these classes so they cannot be overridden?

I realise this is along question so if you think it's better to point me at a book/web site on OOP/ design patterns then do so.

Also, if you see a fault in my OO design that I fail to see then please point it out. Thank you!

Comment: "Every time an instance of Machine is created" - `Machine` is a static class so _there are no instances of_ `Machine`.  All it is is a vessel for some static properties and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even though nothing is in the constructor of each class, will the instance see that the class has those specific attributes or do they have to be newly created in the constructor?

I *think* you're asking if properties will be initialized to a new instance by default, in which case the answer is no.  Properties need to be initialized or they will have a default value, which is `null` for reference types.

> Am I using the 'static' keyword correctly here?

Probably not, but that's just based on other comments within your question.  I would start by not making *anything* static until you *need* to.

> Should/can I also implement the list of classes as static even though the class itself is not?

Can you?  Sure - the property is then tied to the *class*, not a specific *instance*.  Should you?  That depends completely on the usage.  Again, start by not making it static and change it when you need to.

> Should I also implement the keyword `sealed` in any of these classes so they cannot be overridden?

Is anything `virtual`? Or do you depend on inherited virtual methods like `ToString` or `Equals`?  If so and you want to prevent any inherited classes from messing it up then sure, seal your classes.

Comment: So regarding the 1st question, what I mean is can I reference `Machine.cpu`? Because I reference the CPU class in Machine by saying `private CPU cpu = new CPU()` can I then reference `cpu` through an instance of Machine? Also, say if I created multiple instances of Machine, but still had nothing in it's constructor, would it still be the same instance of CPU that is used? For example, if I set `hyperthreaded = true` in one instance of Machine, would `hyperthreaded` also be `true` in another instance of Machine if I am not creating another instance of CPU in Machine's constructor?

Comment: Anyway, thank you for all your help! Has really cleared things up for me? I've forgotten the use of `virtual` as to why I've not used it. I will remove all occurrences of `static` and then add it in later